# Doeas $ \int_0^{0.5} \frac{\mathrm dx}{\sin x\ln x} $ exist?

Tags: calculus, improper-integrals

So I have a test next week and I found myself struggled in a question.

> Does $ \  \int_{0}^{0.5} \frac{\mathrm dx}{\sin x\ln x}  \ $ exist ?

So I saw an answer to that question which I do not understand why is it true.

It says that because $\frac{\sin x}{x} \rightarrow 1$ then we just need to check that $ \  \int_{0}^{0.5} \frac{\mathrm dx}{x\ln x }  \ $ exists (which I calculated and that is not true).

But why is it true ?

If there is another way I will be happy to learn.

Thanks in advance !!

Comment: Do you know the comparison test(s)?

Comment: "(Which I calculated and that is true)." That reads as if you came to the conclusion that $\int_0^{1/2} \frac{dx}{x\log x}$ exists. If so, check again.

Comment: @DanielFischer you are right. It is a typo

Comment: You can use $0\le \sin x\lt x$ for $x\gt 0$ instead of the limit statement, to conclude that $\left|\frac{1}{\sin x\ln x}\right|\gt \left|\frac{1}{x\ln x}\right|$.

Comment: @AndréNicolas So from what I understood $ \ \int_{0}^{0.5} \frac{1}{xln(x)}$ is not convergent I can conclude that $\ \int_{0}^{0.5} |\frac{1}{xln(x)}|$ is also not convergent and therefore $\ \int_{0}^{0.5} |\frac{1}{sin(x)ln(x)}|$ is also not convergent, but what does it says about $\ \int_{0}^{0.5} \frac{1}{sin(x)ln(x)}$ ?

Comment: I took absolute value because ln is negative. (There really was no need to.) The absolute value is therefore just $-\frac{1}{\sin x\ln x}$. It is bigger than $-\frac{1}{x\ln x}$, whose integral diverges to $\infty$.

Comment: Ohhhh Thanks !!

Comment: You are welcome. Basically it comes down to the fact that near $0$, $\frac{\sin x}{x}$ is close to $1$, indeed a bit below. One has to be careful about inequality statements, since $\ln x$ is negative.

Answer (score 4):

At $x=0$, the integrand behaves as $1/(x \log{x})$, which has integral

$$\int \frac{d(\log{x})}{\log{x}} = \log{\log{x}}$$

which blows up there.  The integral thus diverges.